# Regex to count the instances of '?' that are in quotes

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make a regex that will count every question mark that is inside of quotes. This regex is being tested in javascript but I intend to use it for PHP if that matters. I have something that kind of works but not well enough.

Here it is.

```
/(\"|\')(([^\"\'\\]|\\.)*)\?(([^\"\'\\]|\\.)*(\"|\'))/g
```

As you can probably see I also want to ignore escaped quotes.

Say I have the string `"hello? \"world?\""`. This will return 1 which is correct.

But as for this `"hello? \"world??\""`. This will also return 1, but what I want is 2. How can I accomplish this?

Also extra love if I can get a regex that is the exact opposite of this (counting question marks that are NOT in quotes).

Here's the whole function used for this test if it helps.

```
function countTest(str) {
    regx = /(\"|\')(([^\"\'\\]|\\.)*)\?(([^\"\'\\]|\\.)*(\"|\'))/g;

    test = str.match(regx);
    test = test ? test.length : 0;

    console.log(test);
}
```

EDIT:

Also! I noticed from my own typo in this question the string `hello \"world?\'"` will also return 1. That seems easy to fix though.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this o:

Comment: What should I do then? Maybe loop through the string and test that way? Would that be more efficient?

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't but it definitely would be much readable. If someone else meets this countTest function he will not understand what it was for.

Comment: holy inappropriate application of technology, batman

Answer (score 0):

So I just tried it, and apparently the reason the 1 is displayed is, because test is treated not as a String, but as an array.  So I would replace

```
test = test ? test.length : 0;
```

by

```
test = test ? new String(test).length - 3 * test.length + 1: 0;
```

In other words, you are subtracting the 3 characters "," from the String value of the array, but add the 1 because there is no comma character for the first array element.

Edit: For the counting question marks *outside* quotes, just simply subtract the number given above from the number of total question marks in the string.

Edit: for PHP, you would probably use the array_slice function instead of new String(test), with the multiplication and addition constants adjusted as necessary.

Comment: Well, the point is that, the result is an array of each sequence of matches. In other words, if you had a string something like \"Hello?\"??\"World???\", you would get an array "?","???", and you would need to add len(test[0])+len(test[1]) = 1 + 3 to get the number of question marks in quotes. So according to this formula, it would be equal to len("?","???")-3*2+1 = 9-6+1 = 4.

Comment: Relying on specifics of the array stringization seems non-robust. Why not simply `test.length-1`? This is the number of backref matches. In fact I think the regex needs to be adjusted with a few `?:` to prevent non-`?` from being treated as backrefs.

Comment: Just in case you missed it, someone else also posted the same question; my post above answered that question, and at that point they just removed their question.  Read my post above and see if it doesn't answer your question.